# how to set BottomNavigationView items in the center in android (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview, layout-gravity

I have 3 items in my BottomNavigationView that I resized every Item with this code :

```
  val menuView = bottomNavigation.getChildAt(0) as BottomNavigationMenuView

        for (i in 0 until menuView.childCount) {
            val iconView = menuView.getChildAt(i).findViewById<View>(android.support.design.R.id.icon)
            val layoutParams = iconView.layoutParams
            val displayMetrics = resources.displayMetrics
            layoutParams.height = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20f, displayMetrics).toInt()
            layoutParams.width = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20f, displayMetrics).toInt()
            iconView.layoutParams = layoutParams

        }
```

now this item isn't in the center of BottomNavigationView. may please help me to put every item in the center of BottomNavigationView with Kotlin method ?!

Comment: sure. I'll fix this. sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try below thing

**Solution 1**

```
public static void disableShiftMode(BottomNavigationView view) {
        BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
        try { 
            Field shiftingMode = menuView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(true);
            shiftingMode.setBoolean(menuView, false);
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(false);
            for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
                //noinspection RestrictedApi 
                item.setShiftingMode(false);
                // set once again checked value, so view will be updated 
                //noinspection RestrictedApi 
                item.setChecked(item.getItemData().isChecked());
            } 
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to get shift mode field", e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to change value of shift mode", e);
        } 
    }
```

**Solution 2**

If you are using latest support libs then you can go this this solution.
add this line in xml

```
app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"


<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/home_bottom_bg_selector"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/home_bottom_text_selector"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/home_bottom_text_selector"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

Comment: Solution 2 not worked because this : app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
and for Solution 1, I use Kotlin for a whole project dear Mehul Kabaria

Comment: can you please update your question with your required UI.

Comment: I did dear  Mehul Kabaria

Comment: what is "mShiftingMode" here?